# Difficulty with tuning motor PID controller

Tags: arduino, motor, pid

I am struggling for a while now with tuning PID control on my motors. I have bought different motor driver boards better motors etc but still I am unable to get a good control on the motors.

What I am trying to do is give a setpoint in RPM and the PID controller should reach this setpoint (pretty straight forward I guess). I use at the moment two Pololu 4755 motors which have encoders built on them. I have connected them to a Pololu TB9051FTG motor driver board. As µController I use a Nano IoT it counts with interrupts the amount of pulses in a time interval of 100 ms and then computes the rpm value.

This value I parse to the PID controller, found at the Arduino Library (PID_v1.h) , as input. The output is a PWM signal that should control the motor.

I have started with Kp and increases it up to oscillation occurs and that used the half of that value as a starting point. If I do so (Ki and Kd are set to 0) I have already a huge error i.e. 30%. Then I tried to adjust the Kd and Ki but the system will never gets stable. I'm completely lost I don't know where to start fixing this issue. Is it my code is it hardware or is it the way I tune the controller.

So I hope someone can help me fixing this issue I would be very happy to understand this problem. Below I have posted the code I currently use.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <PID_v1.h>

#define ENC_COUNT_REV 16                          // Motor encoder output pulses per 
rotation, property of the encoder see comments above.
#define ENC_IN_LEFT 2                             // Interrupt pin for Left encoder 
input pulses per rotation
#define ENC_IN_RIGHT 3                            // Interrupt pin for Right encoder 
input pulses per rotation
#define PWM_Left_Motor 10                         // Left Motor PWM output to Motor 
driver board
#define DIR_Left_Motor 5                          // Direction output for left motor, 
High is one direction and Low other direction
#define Enable_Left_Motor 4                       // Enable pin for left motor
#define PWM_Right_Motor 11                        // Right Motor PWM output to Motor 
drive board
#define DIR_Right_Motor 7                         // Direction output for right motor, 
High is one direction and Low other direction
#define Enable_Right_Motor 6                      // Enable pin for right motor

volatile long encoderValueLeft = 0;               // Pulse values from encoder outputs
volatile long encoderValueRight = 0;

long previousMillisLeft = 0;                      // Counters for duration measurement 
of intervals for left and right motors
long previousMillisRight = 0;
long currentMillisLeft = 0;
long currentMillisRight = 0;

int rpmLeft = 0;                                  // Variables for RPM measurements
int rpmRight = 0;

int interval = 100;                               // Constant for measurement interval, 
during this interval the amount of pulses is counted 

int PWM_Left_Motor_Output = 0;
int PWM_Right_Motor_Output = 0;

// PID variables 
double Setpoint;
double LeftInput;
double RightInput;
double LeftOutput;
double RightOutput;

PID PID_Control_Left_Motor(&LeftInput, &LeftOutput, &Setpoint, 1, 0, 0, DIRECT);
PID PID_Control_Right_Motor(&RightInput, &RightOutput, &Setpoint, 0.035, 0.5, 2, 
DIRECT);

void updateEncoderLeft()
{
  encoderValueLeft++;                           // Increment the value with 1 each time 
 the interrput is called
}

void updateEncoderRight()
{
  encoderValueRight++;                            // Increment the value with 1 each 
 time the interrput is called
}

void setup() 
{
 Serial.begin(9600); 

  pinMode(ENC_IN_LEFT, INPUT_PULLUP);               // Set the pin as input with 
  internal pullup resistors
  pinMode(ENC_IN_RIGHT, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PWM_Left_Motor_Output, OUTPUT);           // Set output PWM channels
  pinMode(PWM_Right_Motor_Output, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR_Left_Motor, OUTPUT);                  // Set direction control pins
  pinMode(DIR_Right_Motor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Enable_Left_Motor, OUTPUT);               // Set enable motor control pins
  pinMode(Enable_Right_Motor, OUTPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ENC_IN_LEFT), updateEncoderLeft, RISING);       
  //Attach an interrupt 
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ENC_IN_RIGHT), updateEncoderRight, RISING);     
  //Attach an interrupt 

  previousMillisLeft = millis();
  previousMillisRight = millis();

 // Set setpoint to 5000rpm
 Setpoint = 5000;

 PID_Control_Left_Motor.SetSampleTime(50);
 PID_Control_Right_Motor.SetSampleTime(100);

 PID_Control_Left_Motor.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
 PID_Control_Right_Motor.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
 }

 void loop() 
 {
  // Configure motor direction and enable motors
  digitalWrite(DIR_Left_Motor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(DIR_Right_Motor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Enable_Left_Motor, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Enable_Right_Motor, HIGH);

  // Update left RPM value
  currentMillisLeft = millis();
  if (currentMillisLeft - previousMillisLeft > interval)  // Call this loop if the interval time has passed
  {
      previousMillisLeft = currentMillisLeft; // Reset previousTime for next computation
      rpmLeft = (double) (encoderValueLeft * 600 / ENC_COUNT_REV); // Compute the speed in rpm with the total amount of pulses counted by the interrupt
      Serial.print("Left speed = ");  // Serial print only for debugging
      Serial.println(rpmLeft);
      LeftInput = rpmLeft;
      encoderValueLeft = 0; // Reset the encoderValue to 0 
   }

  // Update right RPM value
  currentMillisRight = millis();
  if (currentMillisRight - previousMillisRight > interval) // Call this loop if the interval time has passed
   {
    previousMillisRight = currentMillisRight; // Reset previousTime for next computation
    rpmRight = (double) (encoderValueRight * 600 / ENC_COUNT_REV);// Compute the speed in rpm with the total amount of pulses counted by the interrupt
    Serial.print("Right speed = "); // Serial print only for debugging
    Serial.println(rpmRight);
    RightInput = rpmRight;
    encoderValueRight = 0; // Reset the encoderValue to 0 
    }

   PID_Control_Left_Motor.Compute();
   PID_Control_Right_Motor.Compute();

   // Set a PWM output to the motors
   analogWrite(PWM_Left_Motor, LeftOutput);
   analogWrite(PWM_Right_Motor, RightOutput);
 }
```

Comment: Please try to refine your question into something that can be fully captured in your writeup. You've included your code, but little to no information about your system, nor what's not working with your approach besides a qualitative statement that it's not working. People here can take guesses as to what's wrong but not really "answer" your question. They might get lucky guessing something, but odds are that you'll only get a partial answer.

Comment: This site s best for *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. In that summary I want to emphasize the "answerable" element. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the rate that you are sampling and controlling the motor.  A 10Hz sample rate for PID control is extremely slow.  In my experience, 1000Hz to 2000Hz sampling provides reliable control.

Comment: Note that the appropriate sampling and control rate is very dependent on the system which you are controlling. You have to be well above the natural frequency of the system. If it's a small fast system, you have to sample at a high rate. If it's a larger higher inertia system it's not useful to sample super fast.